# Is wordpress truly capable of anything other than blogging?

Tags: cms

I'm looking at making a pretty intensive social network on Wordpress, and I do see some great plugins that seem well implemented. I've been working with Wordpress for years and would make a good bit of custom areas, etc, but I'd like to not start from scratch. Is Wordpress truly capable of this while still being able to scale, or am I completely off base here?

Comment: Yes it's and no you're not. --- Annotation: I wasn't sure if your question is primarily opinion-based or too broad. I decided to close vote with the latter. --- Please take a look at the [help] for more information on asking and answering on here.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is capable of everything, true but some features will need to be developed from scratch. But still, with WordPress you can save tons of hours of coding

Also, this is an on going project that runs for few good years so be sure you are getting a great DB structure, fast and secured system, friendly interface and much more

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to add social features, start with BuddyPress as a base. You still have to add a good deal of code to get what you want, but this gives you a solid foundation to get it up and started.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin capability is there and everything else can be built on the LAMP stack. Your main concern here is probably going to be building to scale if you expect to receive ample traffic. I'm working on a related project that is being built within AWS, so scaling can be accomplished when needed with minimal effort.

Build / plan a solid infrastructure and you'll be fine.

Let me know if you have any questions, I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress can run any type of website.  Here are some good stats about WordPress.

https://managewp.com/14-surprising-statistics-about-wordpress-usage